# Arrow between two nodes in two different tikzpictures

Tags: latex, tikz

I have a tikzpicture where I use two `def` blocks to define two unique figures. I want to draw an arrow between two nodes and each of them locate in each `def` block. There are IDs assigned to each node, but the arrow I get is not what I want.

```latex
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\def\clusterone{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    \foreach \radius [count=\angleCount from 0] in {0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5}
        {\node[draw=green, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt, fill=green] (c1-\angleCount) at ({\radius * cos(90 * \angleCount)}, {\radius * sin(90 * \angleCount)}) {};}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\def\clustertwo{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    \foreach \radius [count=\angleCount from 0] in {0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6}
        {\node[draw=green, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt, fill=green] (c2-\angleCount) at ({\radius * cos(90 * \angleCount)}, {\radius * sin(90 * \angleCount)}) {};}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\scalebox{1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rotate=30] (node1) at (0, 1.5) {\clusterone};
    \node[] at (0, 1.5) {1};
    \node[rotate=30] (node2) at (0, 0) {\clustertwo};
    \node[] at (0, 0) {2};
    
    \draw[->] (c1-0) -- (c2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

| Expected | Current Result |
| --- | --- |
| [image: expected] | [image: current] |

Is there a way to address IDs of two nodes that are located inside two different tikzpictures? Or is there a way to draw an arrow between nodes in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't nest tikz pictures!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\def\clusterone{%
    \foreach \radius [count=\angleCount from 0] in {0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5}
        {\node[draw=green, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt, fill=green] (c1-\angleCount) at ({\radius * cos(90 * \angleCount)}, {\radius * sin(90 * \angleCount)}) {};}
}

\def\clustertwo{%
    \foreach \radius [count=\angleCount from 0] in {0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6}
        {\node[draw=green, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt, fill=green] (c2-\angleCount) at ({\radius * cos(90 * \angleCount)}, {\radius * sin(90 * \angleCount)}) {};}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[yshift=1.5cm]
    \clusterone
  \end{scope}
  \node[] at (0, 1.5) {1};
  \begin{scope}
    \clustertwo
  \end{scope}
  \node[] at (0, 0) {2};
  \draw[->] (c1-0) -- (c2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, the key is to not nest tikz pictures.